# Adapt ImageView size to image inside

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

In a scrollable view, I am displaying the details about something that contains some images. So my view is not a RecyclerView or a ListView, but a long form that contains TextView and other components, and then a list of images to be downloaded from the internet.
Here is the layout of this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/picturesTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/reference_view_pictures"
                style="@style/FormSubheader"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/pictures"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity, I'm using Picasso to download images into ImageViews that are dynamically added to the pictures LinearLayout:

```
for(picture in reference!!.pictures) {
    val imageView = ImageView(this)
    imageView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
    Picasso.with(this)
           .load(picture)
           .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_hourglass_empty_black_48dp)
           .into(imageView)
    pictures.addView(imageView)
}
```

Images are successfully loaded and everything, but for some reason, despite the layout_height of the ImageView being set to WRAP_CONTENT, when the image is loaded, the ImageView's height is much bigger that the image it contains, so I have huge whitespace inbetween images that I would like to remove.

Can somebody please help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: Try to add this line `imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Vasyl! It worked!